# An extra popViewControllerAnimated: when the user presses the Back button?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

When the user presses the Back button to pop the current UIViewController from the active UINavigationController, I need - in a certain special case - to programmatically pop another UIViewController (the new top one) from the same navigation controller.

(Without going into details, please believe me that this does NOT violate Apples' human interface guidelines. On the contrary, if I do not pop the extra VC it may violate the guidelines).

The only way I could think of is to place a `popViewControllerAnimated:` in `viewWillDisappear:`, but unfortunately this doesn't work (even though the VC that I want to pop still appears as the last object in `self.navigationController.viewControllers`). I tried both YES and NO in the call.

I couldn't find a way to detect when a VC is about to be popped before `viewWillDisappear:` because `UINavigationControllerDelegate` doesn't have a behavior to detect when a VC is about to be popped, only when it's about to be pushed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So, what you were trying to do is to present/push a third VC immediately right after you press the back button to pop the 2nd VC to get back to the first VC?

Comment: No. What I want is to pop from the 3rd VC directly to the 1st VC when the user touches the Back button in the 3rd VC (and as I said, this is not against Apple's HIG in this particular case).

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice new methods in iOS5 that you can use for detecting if you're about to be popped.

See the UIViewController Containment section.

```
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately these are just synchronous detecting methods that don't help me. I need a code that is executed asynchronously when the user touches the Back button and before the current view controller is popped.

Comment: You can check that in viewWillDisappear. I use it that way.

Comment: As I said, I did try viewWillDisappear. Popping a VC in viewWillDisappear does nothing.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You need to either add that check in the previous UIViewController, or retain the navigationController and use the retained one in viewWillDisappear. iOS already nilled out navigationController there so any further calls just go to nil.

Comment: Steipete, the UINavigationController is not nilled out in viewWillDisappear, only in viewDidDisapper. However, self.navigationController.viewControllers at this point doesn't contain the VC that is being popped.